# Why is it acceptable in US politics to insult one another?

Tags: united-states, debate

[Insults fly as Haley's rise makes her target at U.S. Republican debate](https://news.yahoo.com/fourth-us-republican-debate-pits-111752523.html)

How is it that it's acceptable to insult one another in US presidential debates? Like yeah, it might win momentary brownie points, but if any one of the candidates throwing insults actually wins the election, and they have to attend bilateral meetings with Putin / Xi Jinping etc., voicing insults would be one of the least productive things they could do. (And they're getting a lot of practice voicing insults on stage & live TV.)

I'm wondering why the candidates aren't censured for civility the way SE Moderators censure SE. Surely it can be done; Macron and Le Pen [did it](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/apr/20/macron-le-pen-debate-key-moments-in-the-french-election-head-to-head) in 2022.

Comment: It's not what watchers of these debates want? Decency and civility are not seen as virtues anymore in the US? A side effect of populism? Free speech trumps etiquettes?

Comment: Because presidential debates are not a formal or official or legal process, but part of the advertising and marketing of the candidate.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution Please don't answer in the comments, they're for clarification. Feel free to write an answer fleshing it out though. Same for Nij. Those both sound like reasonable theories to me.

Comment: @LioElbammalf But I don't have an answer here. Maybe it is something like this, maybe not. Just couldn't resist giving some prompts that immediately come to mind, whether they are true or not. I definitely don't feel confident enough to write anything of that as an answer.

Comment: Voting not to close - This Q can be answered factually (the answer is "freedom of expression" in the US).

Comment: @sfxedit Being allowed to do it because the "freedom of expression" and it being acceptable are different matters. There are plenty of things we are allowed to do because of the rights we are granted but that does not mean that we should actually be doing them.

Answer (score 3):

Acceptable by whom?

- Judges: Insults have long deemed to be opinion, and as such not actionable under laws like libel that may limit freedom of speech. Specially against public figures, and political speech is specially protected.

  And that is true in many other democratic countries. If the political discourse is more moderated (*), it will be mostly because the candidates think that insulting the opponent may backfire.
- Moderators: Each debate will have an agreed set of rules of what can and cannot be said, and each moderator will have their own criteria of what is acceptable or not within those rules.

  Political candidates have freely chosen to participate in the debate and so, they do accept these rules and moderation.
- Voters: Maybe some of the potential voters will take note of the insults, and refuse to vote for the candidate throwing them.

  This would be the ultimate form of censure to a politician, and the one that really worries them. But that depends on each voter opinion.

(*) And of course, maybe it only looks to you that this only happens in the USA because you only have information about the USA. The article tells how Hailey was called "fascist" and "corrupt". That is not uncommon to hear in Spain(**).

(**) Funny thing, far-right supporters of Vox and their sidekicks from PP have made a point of constantly calling the democratically elected PM "dictator" and "fascist", while at the same time glorifying the former dictator Franco and fighting toe and nail any attempt to remove the honors given to him.

Answer (score 1):

**Because nothing is as insulting as the truth may be.**

At the time when it was not permissible to insult a king, a good king had a [jester](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sta%C5%84czyk) to speak out the truth. Ignoring the truth causes the king to do blunders.

The boundary between strong criticism and insulting speech is rather thin, so relatively little protection exists strictly against "insulting". If the criticism is groundless, better to handle the case as defamation. Defamation is not permitted.